# WIN+CUDA 6.5.19+compute_52 --ptxas-options=-v not showing output

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

---

I am trying to compile some sources to the last Titan X device on a Win machine. Unfortunately, to compile them on Win 7 the unique resource is CUDA 6.5.19. I am also trying to obtain additional information about PTX output by means of the typical flag --ptxas-options=-v. None the less, when I use the following instruction

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 --ptxas-options=-v --machine 64 --compile -cudart static   -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_USRDLL -D_WINDLL -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MD  " -o myFile.cu.obj "myFile.cu"
```

nothing is displayed. **note:** I've seen that usual *compute_xx,sm_xx* have been replaced by *compute_52,compute_52*.

On the other hand, if I use the same functionality for the previous architectures (i.e. 5.0),

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 --ptxas-options=-v --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_USRDLL -D_WINDLL -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MD  " -o myFile.cu.obj "myFile.cu"
```

the output is as expected.

```
1>  ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z15g_restart_checkPi' for 'sm_50'
1>  ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z15g_restart_checkPi
1>      0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
1>  ptxas info    : Used 4 registers, 328 bytes cmem[0]
```

Is there any known issue about this functionality? Any ideas to obtain the desired information?

Comment: @robert, there is an update of it (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx) that allows to compile with compute_52. Anyway, i am installing 7.0 and i'll be in touch! Thanks.

Comment: There's a problem in your VS settings.  This code generation switch: `-gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\"` does not actually specify the generation of any GPU machine code, as only virtual architectures (`compute_xx`) are being specified.  The created executable (with the proper toolkit) would *only* have PTX embedded in it, and the `ptxas` tool (which converts PTX to GPU machine code, i.e. SASS) would never be called during the compilation process.  Therefore the `--ptxas-options=-v` switch would have no effect.  So you'll need to fix your VS settings also.

Comment: Sorry, got my version numbers all mixed up.  You are correct, 6.5.19 should support cc5.2.   The problem is not in the toolkit version (you need the 6.5.19 update) but in the specification of architecture targets.  You need an architecture target `sm_52` to specify the generation of cc5.2 SASS code (which will cause `ptxas` to be invoked.)

Comment: You're right! compilling with both compute_52 flags is not exactly well done. I've upgrade to 7.0 (which i thought it was not supported on Win 7 but it is) and compilation with compute_52,sm_52 has produced the desired information. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RobertCrovella and Alacasta, You could add that comments as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The `--ptxas-options=-v` switch for [nvcc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#abstract) instructs the "compiler" to generate additional output about functions that have been compiled.

`nvcc` is actually a compiler-driver and does many things "under the hood".  Furthermore, `nvcc` can embed both PTX, and/or SASS in a CUDA executable. PTX is an intermediate code format that *still must be compiled* by a sub-tool called `ptxas`, in order to generate GPU machine-executable code, called SASS.

In a nutshell, when you specify virtual architecture targets of the form `compute_XX`, this instructs `nvcc` as to the type of PTX you want to generate, and possibly embed in the executable.  When you specify a physical GPU target of the form `sm_XX`, you are identifying the types of GPU machine code (SASS) that you want embedded in the executable.

The tool that converts PTX to SASS is `ptxas`.  The switch in question here is a switch that guides `ptxas` behavior.  But if you *only* specify virtual architecture targets (which is legal), then your executable will contain only PTX (no SASS) and *`ptxas` will not be called during the compilation process*.

That is what is happening here, and why the expected output from the ptxas switch is not seen.  The solution is to add a physical GPU target (`sm_52` in this case) to the `nvcc` compile command.